# C# how to format readline output

Tags: c#, format, readline

currently, I have read line outputting on rich text box a line from a text file however I want to format that line

```
 if (UsernameCheckers.Text != "Username")
            {
                string line;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"\\studprint2\PCOUNTER\DATA\REJECT.LOG"))
                {
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.IndexOf(UsernameCheckers.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(line.ToString() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                DisplayBox.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
```

an example will be

BCROSS11,Documentname.doc,\STUDPRINT2\computername,15/05/2010,14:48,\1234566788,Insufficient balance,,,/Ts=4BEEA622,107502,10,,

and i want it to say

```
Username: BCROSS11

File name: Documentname.doc

Error: Insufficient balance

Date: 15/05/2010,14:48

Computer name: \STUDPRINT2\computername
```

what do i do?

Comment: `string.Split`.

Comment: Do you need to read the file into one string? How does the file's content really look like? Can you parse it into an array or a structure to better format it?

Comment: Looks like what you have is a csv file. You can split the string as others suggested. Or you can use any opensource library like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: its current a.log file (text file) that has lots and lots of BCROSS11,Documentname.doc,\STUDPRINT2\computername,15/05/2010,14:48,\1234566788,Insufficient balance,,,/Ts=4BEEA622,107502,10,,
in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pieces of your string remain at each line in the same order, you can use
the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method and slice it in the parts that you need.

Here is a small console application to illustrate the use in your case:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = @"BCROSS11,Documentname.doc,\STUDPRINT2\computername,15/05/2010,14:48,\1234566788,Insufficient balance,,,/Ts=4BEEA622,107502,10,,";

    // Split the string and it will return an array of strings
    string[] split_array = test.Split(',');

    // Test output to the console
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", split_array));
    Console.WriteLine("END");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
BCROSS11
Documentname.doc
\STUDPRINT2\computername
15/05/2010
14:48
\1234566788
Insufficient balance


/Ts=4BEEA622
107502
10


END
```

Now you can count the lines and you will know at which position you have to pull out the information. Don't forget that the index starts with `0` and not `1`!
Note please that a string: `",,,"` will be split into 3 empty string. This is why in the output you have empty lines.